# Fantasy/horror book set in WWII London, ends with a monster made of swastikas?

Tags: story-identification

Set in WWII, fantasy/horror children's book. It ends with a giant monster made of Nazism/swastikas that tries to destroy London. I think the monster was an incarnation of all the evil around them or something. I read it in the late 90s/early 00s.

Comment: You've provided some helpful details, but every little bit helps, take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/a/68872) to see if you can [edit] in anything extra

Comment: Text, or a graphic novel?  If the latter, it sounds a bit like *Maus*.

Comment: Text, Young Adult fiction. The author had a few different stories but this is the only one I remember anything about! Don't think it's Maus, but thanks!